# Given a dictionary, getting all possible sub-dictionary configurations possible

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, combinations, enumeration, python-itertools

I am having the following difficulty:
Given my input dictionary with 4 keys and their values e.g.

```
global_dict = {'Cloudy': (False, True),
               'Rain': False,
               'Sprinkler': (False, True),
               'WetGrass': (False, True)}
```

I want to get all possible sub dictionaries with only one value for each key; preferably in a list e.g.

```
dict_list = [
    {'WetGrass': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'Cloudy': False},
    {'WetGrass': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'Cloudy': True},
    {'WetGrass': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'Cloudy': False},
    {'WetGrass': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'Cloudy': True},
    {'WetGrass': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'Cloudy': False},
    {'WetGrass': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'Cloudy': True},
    {'WetGrass': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'Cloudy': False},
    {'WetGrass': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'Cloudy': True}
]
```

I tried already the following:

```
src = {'lblA': (False, True), 'lblB': (False, True), 'lblC': (0, 1, 2)}
labels, terms = zip(*src.items())
print [dict(zip(labels, term)) for term in itertools.product(*terms)]
```

From here:

[Best way to enumerate a cartesian product with labels in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299927/best-way-to-enumerate-a-cartesian-product-with-labels-in-python)

But I keep getting the error:

> TypeError 'bool' object is not iterable

I hope someone can help me out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial problem here is that all of your values are tuples except `'Rain'` (which value is `bool` and it is not iterable), so i've made it tuple as well:

```
global_dict = {'Cloudy': (False, True),
               'Rain': (False,),
               'Sprinkler': (False, True),
               'WetGrass': (False, True)}
```

where `(False,)` is single-element tuple.

Finally we can create `dict_list` using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) like

```
from itertools import product

global_dict = {'Cloudy': (False, True),
               'Rain': (False,),
               'Sprinkler': (False, True),
               'WetGrass': (False, True)}

possible_values = product(*global_dict.values())
dict_list = [dict(zip(global_dict.keys(), values))
             for values in possible_values]
```

gives us

```
>>>dict_list
[{'Cloudy': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'WetGrass': False},
 {'Cloudy': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'WetGrass': True},
 {'Cloudy': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'WetGrass': False},
 {'Cloudy': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'WetGrass': True},
 {'Cloudy': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'WetGrass': False},
 {'Cloudy': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'WetGrass': True},
 {'Cloudy': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'WetGrass': False},
 {'Cloudy': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'WetGrass': True}]
```

## Test

```
desired_dict_list = [
    {'WetGrass': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'Cloudy': False},
    {'WetGrass': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'Cloudy': True},
    {'WetGrass': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'Cloudy': False},
    {'WetGrass': False, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'Cloudy': True},
    {'WetGrass': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'Cloudy': False},
    {'WetGrass': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': False, 'Cloudy': True},
    {'WetGrass': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'Cloudy': False},
    {'WetGrass': True, 'Rain': False, 'Sprinkler': True, 'Cloudy': True}
]

assert (len(dict_list) == len(desired_dict_list) and
        all(dictionary in dict_list
            for dictionary in desired_dict_list))
```

Comment: Hey Azat thank you very much! That was exactly what I wanted to achieve! Can you explain me why I got the error above? And what does the * in front of global_dict.values() do? What is its effect?

Comment: @SolingerMUC: ok, give me a minute

Comment: I do not see where and how you changed the boolean value into a tuple :O

Comment: @SolingerMUC: `(value,)` is a single-element tuple, but remember that `(value)` will not create tuple, so comma is significant

Comment: But how do you change it if in the given global_dict the value ist only a boolean variable ?

Comment: @SolingerMUC: is it your case?

Comment: Yes in my code I get the global dict and some of the values are single boolean variables so I cannot just change them "manually" to single-element tuples :S

Comment: @SolingerMUC: all other objects are tuples?

Comment: Not always, it is possible, that some other keys also have boolean values instead of tuples. It is even possible, that all values are boolean. In that case this list should only contain one element, because there are no other combinations possible.

Comment: @SolingerMUC: there are only `tuple`s and `bool`s in this `dict`?

Comment: Yes and if there are tuples, they are always the tuple (False,True)

Comment: Hey Azat, I think your solution on tuples is sufficient for me! In effect it does not make sense that there are different types (e.g. bool and tuple). I just changed all boolean variables into a single-element tuples! Thanks a lot for your help!